# Is it possible to dynamically refresh a HighCharts drilldown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to refresh a HighCharts Drilldown. In order to this, I have setup a series and drilldown in the usual manner.

The code to fill the first level of the drilldown is fine, but the second level is not being changed to ([10,5,1]). The code is

```
 $('#button').click(function() {
    chart.series[0].setData([10],[10,5,1] ); 
 });   
});
```

Have a jsfiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/bd1v6tew/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can access / override the data via `chart.options.drilldown.series`. For example:

```
 $('#button').click(function() {
        // force highchart to close a open drilldown
        // otherwise the data will not be updated, or 
        // chart will not work any longer
        if (chart.drilldownLevels.length > 0) {
            chart.drillUp();
        }
        chart.series[0].setData([10]); 
        // structure to replace the old data
        var newdrilldown = [{
            id: 'item1',
            data: [
                {
                    name: 'Condition 1',
                  y: 10
                },
                 {
                    name: 'Condition 2',
                  y: 5,
                },
                {
                    name: 'Condition 3',
                  y: 1,
                }]
        }];
        // here you access your drilldown
        chart.options.drilldown.series = newdrilldown; 
});
```

In case you don't want to replace the complete block but just the data inside you go for `chart.options.drilldown.series[0].data = []` and so on.

Your updated [fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/bd1v6tew/7/).

Comment: After refreshing the data, the drilldown no longer works ?

Comment: @user813813 I think I found what you mean, highcharts stops working if you add / manipulate the data in case the drilldown is open - you have to close it before, see the updated answer and fiddle